# What products similar to "lawn mousse" can I use my own seed mixture with?

Tags: lawn, grass, lawn-repair

There are a number of retail products on the market that allow you to attach to your garden hose and spray-fill areas of lawn that have been damaged. These products all contain their own seed mixture which I would rather not use. I have my own high-grade grass mix that is suited for my climate that I would like to add to something so I can get it to stick on some areas that are sandy and wind-exposed.

**What products (either DIY or retail) are out there that allow me to cheaply hydroseed/patch areas of a lawn with my own grass seed mixture?**

Answer (score 2):

Just use your seeds and some fertilizers, and it is nearly good as the all-in-one products.

These products could have also a layer on seeds, not to allow birds to eat them (bad taste), and some stuffs to combat moss or mushrooms and possibly a selective herbicide (killing "large" leaves plants: the dicotyledons).

If you are in this community, probably you can also evaluate what extra product you need for your lawn. Most of that products are done for people who want quick standard solution.

Comment: The problem is that without using something tacky, it simply will not stay and will get washed away. I am trying to do this inexpensively as I rent and simply wanted to improve some areas of the yard myself as I know the owner has no interest in doing so (the property is in Denver and they are just letting the land appreciate before they tear it down to build condos).

The ground itself is exposed to west winds and some spots will see occasional foot traffic from people ignoring the signs saying not to walk on it. Seeding normally, it will just get beat up before it has a chance.

Answer (score 2):

Having put in a couple lawns in northern Colorado (Loveland), my best advice is going to be more manual effort than you desiring to put into the project. I'm not so sure your desire to use a hydro seeding method is going to work well given your situation.  In the end it might result in not much gained.

I would loosen up the surface with a rake, spread the seed, lightly rake seeds in, add fertilizer, maybe add a thin covering of some mulch stuff, put up multiple ropes (trip lines with signs?) indicating the area is off limits, and keep the area moist by watering lightly many times a day such that nothing washes away.  Then pray that a major thunderstorm does not wash everything away.

And then in 6 weeks, repeat in the areas that did not take well due to the things that caused issues.

Best of luck in your endeavor.

Comment: Thanks for the response. There are a few other quirks in my case that made me want to use something tacky with some firmness. One of them showed up the other day when a neighbor's noxious tree (Siberian Elm) spewed millions of seeds across every property in a 40 yard radius. I wanted to make sure these wouldn't germinate as they can be incredibly difficult to deal with.